# How can I dynamically run a comparison from a string?

Tags: c#, .net, dynamic, evaluation

If I were to have a string with something like this:

```
"if (24 == 24) AND ((true == false) OR (true == true)) AND ('HELLO' != 'WORLD')"
```

How could I dynamically evaluate that in code using C#/.Net?

We have a dynamic "rules engine" where the user defines rules.  So a rule might be

```
if (@Number == 24) AND ((@SomeVal1 == false) OR (@SomeVal2 == true)) 
  AND ('@CustomerFirstName' != '@CustomerLastName').
```

We would like to do a simple search/replace for the @ variables and then evaluate the string.

Comment: Are you looking for "expression parsing" or "run C# code from a string"? Are you looking for writing code yourself or open for libraries?

Comment: Hopefully an already existing library that does this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Treating data as code always carries with it some significant risks, so please think carefully about what security implications this will carry for your application.

C# isn't generally a dynamic language like this, but you can hack in this functionality.  [Here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/11939/Evaluate-C-Code-Eval-Function) is an example of a C# version of `eval`.

Depending on need, expression trees may also be an option, as @Femaref points out.

Comment: This code worked perfectly!!  Thank you!!  And thank everyone else for the recommendations.

Answer (score 2):

You can, but it will take a lot of jumping through hoops. However, the .net framework has [Expression Trees](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397951.aspx) which can be used to generate such expressions and compile them to a lambda.

Answer (score 1):

Apart from Femaref's answer you could also try to interpret the string yourself.

This way then be some sort of DSL (domain specific language). You can read more on DSL's here:

ANTLR (useful tool for building DSL's) http://www.antlr.org/wiki/display/ANTLR3/Antlr+3+CSharp+Target

Answer (score 0):

Im afraid there is no easy way to do it. 
You could either parse your string by hand and then use Reflection to get the variables or fields or properties refered to by your @foo syntax, or you could create a dynamic type with a method that reflects your Rule.

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure how complex expressions you might have. But here is a nice library that i think could handle your example expression.
http://ncalc.codeplex.com/

Comment: This looks great for mathmatical calculations, but not so much boolean evaluations.

Comment: Well boolean evaluation sort of is a mathematical calculation. NCalc library has logical binary operators, we used it sucessfully for similar requirement as yours is. But that were all basic expressions, it all dependes how complex your requirements are.